# Is there a generating function for Hermite polynomials of 2n?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-functions

I want to know if exists a generating function for the hermite polynomials that is $H_{2n}(x)$

Comment: Why can’t you use the generating function for $H_n$ and ignore the odd-index polynomials you don’t need?

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Parity.

Recall 
$$
H_{2n+1}(x) + H_{2n+1}(-x)=0, \qquad H_{2n}(x) + H_{2n}(-x)= 2 H_{2n}(x),
$$
[so that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Generating_function) 
$$
e^{2xt -t^2} + e^{-2xt -t^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (H_{n}(x)+H_n(-x)    ) \frac{t^n}{n!} \\ = 2\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} H_{2m}(x)\frac{ t^{2m}} {(2m)!} ~~ ,
$$
i.e. 
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} H_{2m}(x)\frac{ t^{2m}}{(2m)!}= e^{-t^2} \cosh (2xt)~~,
$$
even in *x*. (You might opt for the variable $\tau = t^2$, instead.)

In any case, this means that
$$
H_{2n}(x) = \partial_t^{2n} (e^{-t^2} \cosh (2xt) ) ~\Big {|} _{t=0} ~~. 
$$

Comment: I think you mean cosh?

Comment: @RobertMcNees   Of course; thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> ....A far more convenient formulation is actually
>   available, which expresses the $\,H_n\,$ in terms of a *generating function*  $\,S\left(\xi,s\right)$.
>   \begin{equation}
> S\left(\xi,s\right)\boldsymbol{=}e^{\xi^2\boldsymbol{-}\left(s\boldsymbol{-}\xi\right)^2}\boldsymbol{=}e^{\boldsymbol{-}s^2\boldsymbol{+}2s\xi}\boldsymbol{=}\sum\limits_{n\boldsymbol{=}0}^{\infty}\dfrac{H_n\left(\xi\right)}{n !}s^n
> \tag{13.10}\label{13.10}
> \end{equation}
>   If the exponential in Eq. \eqref{13.10} is expanded out in powers of $\,s\,$ and $\,\xi\,$, it is seen that a given power of $\,s\,$ is associated only with powers of $\,\xi\,$ equal to that power or less than it by an even integer. Thus $\,H_n\left(\xi\right)\,$ defined in this way is a polynomial of order $\,n\,$ that has the parity of $\,n$.

*"Quantum Mechanics"* Leonard I.Schiff, 3rd Edition 1968.